# AWS Route53 route to two Elastic Beanstalk websites with single SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, subdomain, amazon-route53

I currently have two Elastic Beanstalk apps, and what I would like to do is purchase one domain, such as  example.com. I'd like the domain to route to one of the Beanstalk apps, and then I'd like to create a subdomain such as a.example.com to route to the second Beanstalk app. All of this being through AWS Route 53.

Is this possible? And if so, is it possible to have only one SSL certificate for example.com that would work and be valid for a.example.com? Or would I need two SSL certificates, one for example.com and one for a.example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get a wildcard SSL that included both `example.com` and `*.example.com`.

For creating an SSL, you should use the [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) service within AWS as it will generate and rotate your SSLs at no cost on your managed AWS resources.

Regarding the domains you would have 2 separate records, `example.com` would resolve to one app. And a second record for `a.example.com` that would resolve to the second app.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-resource-record-set) is some more information on setting the DNS records for your elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you! I'm brand new to domains, I'm glad it's possible.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)